# Changing innerHTML when multiple elements have a specific class removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 elements with multiple classes. 5 of them have classes `.home` and `.not-added`, 5 of them have `.away` and `.not-added`. With jQuery when an event happens i toggle the class `.not-added` for a specific element. I want to check when these 10 elements don't have the class `.not-added`, so that i can change the innerHTML of an element.

My method for checking this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ready = false;

        $(".home").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).hasClass(".not-added")) {
                ready = false;
            } else {
                ready = true;
            }
        });
        if (ready) {
            document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "Points";
        }
    });
</script>
```

This doesn't work. When the page is loaded, `#button1` has already `Points` inside of it.

Sample of my elements:

before event:

```
<div class='dropdown-toggle stat-dropdown not-added home' data-toggle='dropdown'>
    ...
</div>
```

after event:

```
<div class='dropdown-toggle stat-dropdown home' data-toggle='dropdown'>
    ...
</div>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: can you share fiddle

Comment: Your loop is not correct. You overwrite `ready` each time through the loop, so it doesn't have information about all 10 elements, just about the last element.

Comment: @Lukas Baliūnas , try my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the class name in `.hasClass()`.
In your case: use `.hasClass('not-added)` instead of the wrong `.hasClass('.not-added')`. Here is a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1ffvetb/3/) with your use case.

Note that it would be better to use a *for loop* instead of `.each()`, because you can utilize the conditional to check for your flag (*ready* in your case), to avoid iterating through all of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here the modified version of your sample code,

https://jsfiddle.net/djsreeraj/j65rwbg2/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
   var ready = false;

$(".home").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("not-added")) {
        ready = false;
    }
    else {
        ready = true;
    }
});

$(".away").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("not-added")) {
        ready = false;
    }
    else {
        ready = true;
    }
});

  //alert(ready);
  if (!ready) {
    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "Points--s";
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home  not-added"></div>
<div class="home  not-added"></div>
<div class="home  not-added"></div>
<div class="home  not-added"></div>
<div class="home  not-added"></div>

<div class="away  not-added"></div>
<div class="away  not-added"></div>
<div class="away  not-added"></div>
<div class="away  not-added"></div>
<div class="away  not-added "></div>

<Button id="button1"> Points
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using `hasClass` in the wrong way, you should pass the class name as parameter (with no `.` cause it's not a selector):

```
if ($(this).hasClass("not-added")) {
```

In your code the condition will be never matched that's why variable `ready` is `true` after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".home").on("click",function(){

        $(this).toggleClass("home clicked");

        if ($(".home").length < 1)

            $("#button1").text("Points");
    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .clicked {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="home not-added">I have class home and not-added (click on me!)</div>
    <div class="home not-added">I have class home and not-added (click on me!)</div>
    <div class="home not-added">I have class home and not-added (click on me!)</div>
    <div class="home not-added">I have class home and not-added (click on me!)</div>
    <div class="home not-added">I have class home and not-added (click on me!)</div>
    <br><br>
    <button id="button1">I am Button</button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="away not-added">I have class away and not-added</div>
    <div class="away not-added">I have class away and not-added</div>
    <div class="away not-added">I have class away and not-added</div>
    <div class="away not-added">I have class away and not-added</div>
    <div class="away not-added">I have class away and not-added</div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".home").on("click",function(){

            $(this).toggleClass("home clicked");
            if ($(".home").length < 1)
                $("#button1").text("Points");
        })

    })
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LukasBaliūnas , try my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `ready` variable each time through the loop, so it doesn't tell you if all the elements don't have the `not-added` class.

Instead of a loop, just check the count of elements with that class.

```
ready = $(".home.not-added").length == 0;
```